# Euler characteristic is equal to self-intersection number of zero-section?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

As I recall (from Guillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology") the Euler characteristic of a  (for my purposes, compact and oriented) smooth manifold X is defined as $\chi(X)=I(\Delta,\Delta)$, where $I(\Delta, \Delta)$ is the intersection number of the diagonal in $X\times X$ with itself.  I have recently become interested in characteristic classes, and in the first page of the notes I'm reading, the author states this definition, and says $\chi(X)$ may equivalently be defined to be $I(X_0,X_0)$, the intersection of the zero-section in the tangent bundle of $X$ with itself.  Can anyone explain how these definitions are equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at first definition. To compute the self-intersection number one needs to deform one of two copies of $\Delta$ slightly to make intersection transversal. It can be done in a small neighborhood of the diagonal — i.e. in the *normal bundle of the diagonal* in $X\times X$. But this normal bundle is isomorphic to the tangent bundle of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I recall proving the normal bundle of the diagonal is isomorphic to the tangent bundle of X, but I'm still not sure how to use this to get equality of the two self-intersections.  I know the diagonal is diffeomorphic to X, which is diffeomorphic to the zero-section.  Can I use the homotopy of $i:\Delta \to X\times X$ to get a homotopy of of the zero-section?  How can I be sure the sum of the signs of the intersection points will coincide?

Comment: Self intersections are not unique. There are many embeddings of the manifold into the tangent bundle that are transverse to the zero section. All of them have the same intersection number and this seems to be the fact you are looking for. Note that such an embedding is just a vector field with isolated zeros. So this just says that the sums of the indices of a vector field with isolated zeros is a constant. The reason the diagonal class is considered is it can be used for a slick calculation of the Euler characteristic.